# Why is this range based for statement returning one number too low?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to calculate the quantity of numbers in a Vector that are divisible by either 3 OR 5. The correct answer is 19, but my code is returning 18.

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong so I can understand? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int count {};

    vector<int> vec {1,3,5,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,25,26,27,30,50,55,56,58,100,200,300,400,500,600,700};

    for(int i=1; i<=vec[i]; ++i)
    {
        if(vec[i] % 3 == 0 || vec[i] % 5 == 0)
        {
        count+=1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Odd Numbers In Vector: " << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I counted manually, and I seem to be getting 18. Maybe your code isn't actually producing the wrong answer. (quick python script suggests that 18 is actually correct: https://repl.it/repls/DodgerblueFamousBookmark)

Comment: That's also not a range-based for statement

Comment: The code causes undefined behaviour because you'll read off the end of the vector eventually

Comment: Since the contents of the vector increase consistently, with steps greater than one, `i <= vec[i]` will always be true. Eventually `i` will not be a valid index of the vector.   Accessing `vec[i]` after that gives undefined behaviour

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vectors, like arrays, are indexed starting at *zero,* not one. In addition, I'm not sure why you're using a *value* in the array to decide the terminating condition.

I suspect your `for` statement should be (using the specific type as well):

```
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
```

There's also two other points I'd like to raise:

1. That's *not* a range-based `for`. A range-based `for` would be something along the lines of `for (auto val: vec)`.
2. Your `if` statements catches multiples of three or five, there's a vast difference between those numbers and the set of all odd numbers that your output statement seems to indicate.

---

Here's how I would write it with a range-based `for` loop, and with the test modified to count odd numbers *and* multiples of three or five (just remove the one you're not interested in):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int countOdd {0};
    int countMult {0};

    vector<int> vec {
          1,   3,   5,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,
         21,  25,  26,  27,  30,  50,  55,  56,  58,
        100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700
    };

    for (const auto val: vec) {
        if (val % 2 == 1)
            ++countOdd;
        if (val % 3 == 0 || val % 5 == 0)
            ++countMult;
    }

    cout << "Count of odd numbers        : " << countOdd << '\n';
    cout << "Count of multiples of 3 or 5: " << countMult << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Was just commenting to you about not having mentioned the terminating condition when your edit appeared. Guess I don't have to leave one now. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I actually wrote the wrong explanation as that was the previous problem I was working on! It should return total amount of numbers divisible by 3 or 5. I'm still learning c++ so that auto val: vec is awesome, thanks for the clarification and example!